# Split a string and check if all elements are unique in R

Tags: r, string, split

I am trying to split a string and then check if all its elements are unique. So far I have done the following:

```
df <- data.frame(
"id" = c("001;002;003", "001;001;001", "001;001;002"),
"v1" = c("a", "b", "c")
)

sapply(strsplit(df$id, ";"), function(x) unique(x) %in% df$id)
```

My intention is to have an output of `FALSE`, `TRUE`, and `FALSE`, respectively for `"001;002;003"`, `"001;001;001"`, and `"001;001;002"`

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can check on the `unique` `length`

```
sapply(strsplit(df$id, ";"), function(x) length(unique(x))== 1)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

or with `n_distinct` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   separate_rows(id) %>% 
   group_by(v1) %>%
   summarise(flag = n_distinct(id) == 1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  v1    flag 
  <chr> <lgl>
1 a     FALSE
2 b     TRUE 
3 c     FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

Or using `table`

```r
sapply(strsplit(df$id, ";"), function(x) length(table(x)) == 1)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the variance.

```
sapply(strsplit(df$id, ';'), var) == 0
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```